# How to detect if a specific mob is dead in 1.15

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to be able to detect if a specific mob is dead and then execute a command. I have already tagged the mob "boss1" and I know that you need a tag to detect the entity but I don't know the commands to actually detect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check for the entity using `/execute`.

```
/execute unless entity @e[tag=boss1] run ...
```

Run the command unless there is an entity with the tag `boss1`.

When the boss dies, you can put the command to run after the `run` parameter.

Comment: Is there a way to make it only run once?

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: I had a repeating blinking circuit activating 2 command blocks with the `/execute unless entity @e[tag=boss1] run ...` command but one had the command I wanted to run and the other had a fill command that stopped the circuit by replacing certain blocks with air.

Comment: Great job, you figured it out! Please consider clicking the check button on the answer you find most useful. Thanks!

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 placing or removing a redstone block next to a repeating command block in order to turn it on or off isn't _that_ bad.  There are other ways to turn a repeating command block on and off, such as setting "Needs Redstone" when there isn't any power around to stop the chain, though.

Comment: Well Ive got it working and I don't expect to use the circuit more than once so Im fine with the solution